# Kdump.service FAILED centOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I'm having `CentOS 7 64` installed on my desktop. After recent system update, I am getting below error while booting the `CentOS 7`.

Some time system is able to boot and I can work on it. but it gives the same error at the time of next boot.

after entering this:

> systemctl status kdump.service

I get this:

> ● kdump.service - Crash recovery kernel arming
>   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kdump.service; enabled)
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-01-22 02:55:49 MST; 39min ago
>   Main PID: 1139 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain kdumpctl[1139]: No memory reserved for crash kernel.
>   Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain kdumpctl[1139]: Starting kdump: [FAILED]
>   Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofisx.jpg): kdump.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofisx.jpg): Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
>   Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofisx.jpg): Unit kdump.service entered failed state.
>   Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofisx.jpg): kdump.service failed.
>
> system-config-kdump:
>   command not found...

Adding image

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Install the required packages**

```
yum --enablerepo=debug install kexec-tools crash kernel-debug kernel-debuginfo-`uname -r`
```

**Modify grub**

A kernel argument must be added to `/etc/grub.conf` to enable kdump. It’s called crashkernel and it can be either auto or set as a predefined value e.g. 128M, 256M, 512M etc.

The line will look similar to the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=rhel/swap crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rhgb quiet"
```

Change the value of the `crashkernel=auto` to `crashkernel=128` or `crashkernel=256` ...

Regenerate grub configuration:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

On a system with UEFI firmware, execute the following instead:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/Centos/grub.cfg
```

Open the `/etc/zipl.conf` configuration file

locate the parameters= section, and edit the crashkernel= parameter (or add it if not present). For example, to reserve 128 MB of memory, use the following:`crashkernel=128M` save and exit

Regenerate the zipl configuration:`zipl`

**⁠Enabling the Service**

To start the `kdump` daemon at boot time, type the following command as root:

```
chkconfig kdump on
```

This will enable the service for runlevels 2, 3, 4, and 5.
Similarly, typing `chkconfig kdump off` will disable it for all runlevels.

To start the service in the current session, use the following command as root:

```
service kdump start
```

Comment: GAD3R not working, edited the question with the current error.

Comment: Change it to  `crashkernel=256M@256M`

Comment: I have tried it till 512 MB still not Woking

Answer (score 1):

This message is pretty google-able:

> Jan 22 02:55:49 localhost.localdomain kdumpctl[1139]: No memory reserved for crash kernel.

The discussion on the [first link on google](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=302649) recommends to use

```
system-config-kdump
```

Or just add `crashkernel=128M` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable in `/etc/default/grub` and run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, as proposed in [the other guide](http://thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-configure-kdump/).

I don't have CentOS 7 around here to try, but I believe you will be able to sort that out with this information.

Comment: Jakuje I have tried this but no luck. still it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check seven line,they show you No memory reserved for crash kernel.It's means you need edit grub file ,give crash kernel some space,usually 128 or 256.

Comment: I given `512` but it is unable to refer that and again gives me the error. this error is occurred approx 2 time every 10 reboot.

Comment: Maybe it's because 512 don't enough to store core file.  You  edit grub file  like "crashkernel=512" or "crashkernel=512M"? It should be "crashkernel=512M".

Comment: Its is set to `512M` Previous was set to `128M`